# printing logs in db2 stored procedure

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a stored procedure and have put some debug messages like

```
call dbms_output.put ('calling clean up on <tableName>');
```

while invoking the procedure, I don't see this line. I am using Aqua data studio for my work. I also did the following while calling the SP

set serveroutput on@ and set serveroutput on

but getting the error like

```
An unexpected token "on@" was found following "set serveroutput ".  Expected tokens may include:  "="
```

Can you please suggest as to how to see the statements which I am putting as kind of logs within a SP? I am using "AquaData Studio - 7.0.39"

Comment: http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio/db2_sql_debugger.html ----
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idm/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.debug.spd.doc/topics/cbsovrv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set serveroutput` is not an SQL statement so it makes no sense to Aqua Data Studio or any other tool, except the IBM DB2 command line processors.

What `dbms_output.put` does is store the line in an internal array in the `dbms_output` module. DB2 tools access that array and print its contents to screen after executing your stored procedure.

You can in a way simulate the same behaviour in Aqua Data Studio by creating an exception handler in your stored procedure where you use `dbms_output.get_lines` to return the line array, then build a cursor from that array using `unnest()` and return the cursor to the calling application (Aqua).

It might be easier though to just create a logging stored procedure of your own, running an autonomous transaction, that would insert log records into a database table that you can query when necessary.

Comment: have got the db2 client installed..looks like it is going to work

Comment: Just be aware that, if your stored procedure causes an exception and rollback, contents of the `dbms_output` buffer will be lost